# Is it possible to return a value of an inner object of the wrapper object in Vuex getter before mounting?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, getter

I am currently working with Vuex and VueJS, and I got stuck in a problem with the Computed property.

In a nutshell, I have **an object which has an inner object** in Vuex state, try to access the key of the inner object in Vuex getter to return the value, and render it in a component. However, I get an error like "cannot read property id of undefined".

I think there are two important points to the problem.

The first one is that I can render the value if I put the value into a variable of the data option in mounted() with using the settimeout() method.

The second point is that I can access a key of an object, return the value in Vuex getter, and render it in a component correctly.

I would like to know if it is possible to return the value of an object in the wrapper object in Vuex getter to render it before mounting a component.

It would be great if you could answer my question. Thank you in advance.

[Sample code of Vuex getter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTfIq.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, you don't have the `_user` property when you are trying to access it via vuex getter. I think you are fetching it from and API, as i understood.

On your state, set profile as empty/nested object with all fetchable properties to get rid of errors.

Like;

```
const state: {
  profile: {
    _user: { _id: null }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I checked whether it works and it worked well.